# Which brush is used in this video?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I was watching this video in which a brush is used to make a sort of "bump" to make mountains. Which brush is it? How can I make the same 3d effect?

https://youtu.be/uR4faVCRc6U?t=2m9s

Comment: And the video is?

Comment: sorry i forgot to liked it

Comment: Ok, it's a long video, could put the exact minute when the brush is used please?

Comment: i have update the link, now it start from 2:09

Answer (score 1):

Paint with a brush using the same color as the background, over a layer with **Bevel and Emboss Effect**.

[image: brush]